# Why can I not move / rotate objects around in the left pane view but on the right?

Tags: animation, interface

I have switched to the Animation tab.
I would like to define how my animation looks at frame 129.
Therefore I have first change "End frame" from 60 to 250.

Then I put the blue cursor line at frame 129, and then I right-clicked and selected "Insert keyframes".

I was expecting that the timeline would show the keyframe, but I didn't notice any change.

Nevertheless, I then tried to move objects to where they should be at frame 129, but when I grabbed, then the usual arrows to move them did not occur.

What am I doing wrong?

After some trying, I have discovered that it does work if I use the right view. As one can see in the right window, I was able to select the object.

On the left side it's not possible.
Why?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You've switched off your view gizmos and overlays. See my answer?

Comment: Check my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have switched off viewport overlays and gizmos. Enable them to see everything again:[image]

**Edit: It works in the right since you have viewport overlays on in the right and not in the left.**

Comment: Thank you. I have enabled them now, but when I click an object, still nothing happens.

Comment: @tmighty can you edit your question to show your viewport overlay and gizmos dropdowns? And also, make sure the object is set to selectable in viewports. Try clicking at an object and press G to move, is it moving? If it is, it means that you disabled something in your viewport overlays. If not, it means that it is set to not be selected in viewports.

Comment: I did, and I have also edited my question, because it turns that out it does work if I use the right side...

Comment: @tmighty because you turned the overlays on on the right side... If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by pressing the checkbox on the left :)

Comment: Thank you! It works now that I have clicked / enabled the logical and / or icon. You are right: On the left it was not enabled. Thank you!